# Testing for hourly seasonality

Tags: seasonality

So I have compiled the hourly log returns for an asset, and grouped it in columns with each column being one hour's returns.

How can I test whether there are seasonal patterns in the returns according to the hour? A GARCH model? Anova? T-test?

Comment: Calculate the average return for the 1st hour of trading (say 8am to 9am), the second hour (9am to 10), the third... Are any of these statistically different from each other? That is what seasonality is, a tendency for returns to be different at different times. ANOVA is indeed one way to test whether N means are equal or different.

Comment: Simply plotting the means, with error bars around each one http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/examples/points1.png will show graphically what is going on, if anything. You can follow up with with more formal tests if required.